# Display dynamic content in mozilla's add-on popup

Tags: javascript, html, json, firefox-addon

I'm developing an add-on to enable people to follow a streamer, but it has been rejected on Mozilla store because it used innerHTML which is not secured. The add-on has two parts :

- Page script : It loads streamers data and run in background to check if they are online. If their status change, the popup content has to be changed.
- Content scripts : Page script cannot change the popup content, so content script has to manage it, but a content script get a "clean view of the DOM", so it cannot see Javascript variables defined by page scripts.

With port.emit, I can send a message from page script to content script. It can be the HTML code I would like to display, or a JSON version of my objects.

My objects before being serialized in JSON :

```
function myObject(parameters)
{
   var link1 = parameters.link1;
   var picture1 = ...;

   var link2 = parameters.link2;
   var picture2 = ...;

   // some functions which can change pictures
}
```

And the HTML code must be like this :

```
<ul>
    <li><a style='background-image: url(myObject1.pictures1)' href='myObject1.link1'</a></li>
    <li><a style='background-image: url(myObject1.pictures2)' href='myObject1.link2'</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li><a style='background-image: url(myObject2.pictures1)' href='myObject2.link1'</a></li>
    <li><a style='background-image: url(myObject2.pictures2)' href='myObject2.link2'</a></li>
</ul>
```

Mozilla's editors sent me this link, saying I would find way to not use innerHTML : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/DOM_Building_and_HTML_Insertion

Now, I don't know what example is relevant to solve my issue. HTML one ? Json one ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

Friend refer following link probably your problem is solve.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Display_a_Popup

Comment: Thanks to your link, I finally suceed to import dynamic content in the popup with DOM functions, but this content has no style, my buttons are only text, even if i'm loading a css file. Is there a way to see source file of the popup ? (right click doesn't work on it)